# Replace templates in strings by array values

Tags: php, regex

I have a string, that can has simple templates. And I have an array with values for replacemenet. Currently I am doing it with loop. But I want to change it to preg_replace. Can you help me?

Example:

```
$values = array(
    'id'   => 120,
    'name' => 'Jim'
);
$string = 'Hello <!name!>. Your ID is <!id!>';
$output = preg_replace(...); // Hello Jim. Your ID is 120
```

Also preg_replace should work not only with id and name, but with any other keys. Thanks.

Comment: I would probably use `preg_replace_callback` and a closure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like the following?

```
<?php
$values = array(
    'id'   => 120,
    'name' => 'Jim'
);
$string = 'Hello <!name!>. Your ID is <!id!>';

function foo($val) {
        return '/<!' . $val . '!>/';
}

echo preg_replace(array_map('foo', array_keys($values)), array_values($values), $string);
```

If the whole thing is in a class:

```
class Template {
        static function bar($val) {
                return '/<!' . $val . '!>/';
        }

        function render($values, $string) {
                echo preg_replace(array_map(array('Template', 'bar'), array_keys($values)), array_values($values), $string);
        }
}

$values = array(
    'id'   => 120,
    'name' => 'Jim'
);
$string = 'Hello <!name!>. Your ID is <!id!>';
$T = new Template();
$T->render($values, $string);
```

Comment: Thanks. Good thing. Can I use class method instead of function for array_map()?

Comment: `preg_replace_callback()` is an alternative.